# Sql query to get rechargevalue and max date on any number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, which have rechargevalue,rechargedate,rechargeno column. i want to retrieve rechargevalue and maximum rechargedate with reference to rechargeno.
Upto now i was retrieved only maximum date but now i want to retrieve rechargevalue also.

Query:

```
SELECT isnull(max(rechargeOn),'01/01/1900') AS rechargeOn 
FROM o_rechargehistory_retailer 
WHERE kno='mobileno'
```

Comment: what is kno ? Is that rechargeno?

Answer (score 2):

Use `top` and `order by`:

```
SELECT top 1 r.*
FROM o_rechargehistory_retailer r
WHERE r.kno = 'mobileno'
ORDER BY r.rechargeOn DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    isnull(max(rechargeOn),'01/01/1900') AS rechargeOn, 
    rechargevalue 
FROM 
    o_rechargehistory_retailer 
WHERE 
    kno='mobileno'
GROUP BY 
    rechargevalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
SELECT kno,rechargevalue, isnull(max(rechargeOn),'01/01/1900') AS rechargeOn 
FROM o_rechargehistory_retailer 
WHERE kno='mobileno'  group by kno;
```